# How to read a url from JSON file before invoking an http get service in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to read a http get service url from JSON file and then invoke a http get service.

I understand how to read  json file asynchronously and how to invoke a rest service in angular 6.

But in my application I want all my rest service in JSON file.I want to first load the url from json and then invoke the service but somehow I am not able to do so as before the url is loaded the service is invoked .

Below is my method to load the json which I am invoking  in ngOnInit() method.My method which invokes the http service is also loaded in ngOnInit() method.

```
private loadURLFromExternalFile(){
    this.httpClient.get('./assets/server_config/server_url_config.json').subscribe(
      data=>{  
        this.serverURLConfig=data as string[];
      },( err: HttpErrorResponse) =>{

      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Be cautious with the indents.  Stack Exchange uses Markup; an indent means you want to write code.

Comment: You should use Resolver for your case.

Comment: Can you include the code that is calling this method and invoking the service

Comment: Sorry for that.Will keep it in mind.Both the methods loadURLFromExternalFile() and getUserList() are invoked from the ngOnInit() method in my Component in sequence.The getUserList()  invokes the http service and loadURLFromExternalFile() loads the json file.

Comment: first resolve your url and then you can use httpClient. this has to be in 2 steps

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
private loadURLFromExternalFile(){
    this.httpClient.get('./assets/server_config/server_url_config.json').pipe(
      switchMap(data=>{
         const serverURLConfig = data as string[];
         return fetchGetServiceData(serverURLConfig);
      })
    )
    .subscribe(response=>{
      console.log(response);
    })
  }

private fetchGetServiceData(urelConfig){
    return this.httpClient.get(urelConfig);
}
```

Comment: Thanks !  Will try with the above solution.